# Bootstrap, how to make a colum stacks to the middle of the preceding column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with the responsivness of my page, here is an illustration, I have this pattern:

[image]
which correspond to this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>


<style type="text/css">



</style>


<body>

<div class="container">

<br><br><br>


  <div class="row" style="background-color: red;">


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

      <div class="row" style="background-color: blue;">
        <br>

      </div>
      <div class="row" style="background-color: green;">

        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <br>
    <br>

    </div>

  </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when I diminish the window size, Bootstrap make the columns/rows stack this way:

[image]

But I need  the yellow part to go between the green and blue part (or at least to cover those 2 parts). I have tried to use absolute positionning on the yellow part but it does not work.

Any solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will result in what you want

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"  style="background-color: blue;">
         <br>     
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: green;">
          <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider doing this:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: red;">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: blue;">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" style="background-color: yellow; float:none; margin:0 -15px; width:calc(100% + 30px);">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="background-color: green;">
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-xs col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```